# Do I need "one" in the following case?

Tags: word-usage

> She wore round framed glasses with the left side slighter bigger than
>   the right (one).

Do I need *one* in the following case? Why or why not?

Comment: "One" and "side" are optional there.  By "bigger" do you mean thicker or having a larger diameter?

Answer (score 2):

I would say 
"She wore round framed glasses with the left side slighter bigger than the right **side**."

In the beginning you are talking about the **side**, so it would be better to end with **side**.

Answer (score 2):

Unrelated to your question about "one": You should say "slightly" instead of "slighter".

> She wore round framed glasses with the left side *slightly* bigger than the right (one).

On to your real question, I think using "side" instead of "one" would sound better. Using "one" sounds a little bit weird. (Although it's not *too* bad) It would make more sense to use "one" if you are referring to two separate objects.

If you decide to leave out side/one, it would sound perfectly fine. The word could be inferred from context. This would be called [ellipsis](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ellipsis).

Comment: DJ sounds right but if you're going to use one of those sentences you should use 'one'

Comment: But side is better then 'one'